# To append a byte[] to a string in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, append, handle

My javascript code sends blobs of data to a handler in C#. My Javascript code is working fine, and I have already tried to receive the data from client(javascript) and pass them to the C# handler and save them in a local Folder.

Instead of saving the data in a folder, I want to now save it in a `string`.
My handler each time gets a piece of my information as a `byte[]`.

my Javascript:

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
// this is not the complete code 
// I slice my file and push them in var blobs = [];
blobs.push(file.slice(start, end));
while (blob = blobs.shift()) {

    xhr.send(blob);
    count++;
}
```

My C# handler:  In here, the `bool ok` never gets set to `true`.
How can I get all my files chunk by chunk as I am sending them from javascript; and, instead of saving in a folder, saving it in a string?

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[context.Request.ContentLength];
        context.Request.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, context.Request.ContentLength);
        string fileSize = context.Request.Headers.Get("X_FILE_SIZE");

        bool ok = false;
        System.Text.StringBuilder myData = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        myData.Append(buffer);
        if(myData.Length == int.Parse(fileSize)){ ok=true;  }

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looking into Encoding.Getstring: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/744y86tc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Depending on the encoding, the length of the byte array and the length of the string may well be different.

Comment: It might be better to convert it to a base64 representation. You could use Convert.ToBase64String - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobase64string(v=vs.110).aspx and Convert.FromBase64String - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string(v=vs.110).aspx. In javascript this would be btoa() and atob().

Comment: What is in the file? Is it text or is it binary data. If you are going to accumulate it in a string on the server side, that implies that it is text. If it is text then why not work with it as text on the JavaScript side? Also, if you are going to send the data in multiple requests, you need to accumulate them in something on the server side that will persist across multiple rquests. You could use something like Session for this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no overload of `StringBuilder.Append` that takes a byte array, so it will call the `StringBuilder.Append(object)` method. That will call `ToString` on the byte array to get a string value, which results in the string `"System.Byte[]"`.

To get the byte array as a string, you need to know what the bytes represent. For example, if the bytes are text that is encoded as UTF-8 then you can use the `Encoding.UTF8` class to decode it:

```
myData.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer));
```

Note that multi-byte encodings like UTF-8 may represent one character as multiple bytes, so the string length may be different from the byte array length.